# What is the order in which different forms of assignments may appear in a python function call?

Tags: python

When I run the following code, I get an error, why is that? Isn't the order of the arguments correct?

```
def f(a, b, c, d):
    print a, b, c, d

f(1, b=2, *(3,), **{'d': 4})
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asad/scripts/l.py", line 9, in <module>
    f(1, b=2, *(3,), **{'d': 4})
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Can you tell us what error you get?

Comment: Because positional arguments have to be passed before keyword ones.

Comment: but shouldn't the * form come after keyword arguments?

Comment: @asad No, it shouldn't. In your code the value of b is both 3 and 2. If you change the order of your arguments, it'll be more clear.

Answer (score 5):

`b=2` in the function call is not a variable assignment but a passing of a keyword argument.

You are passing `b` as a keyword argument yet you're also passing the value `3` (as the second positional argument), which is also `b`.

So `b` is receiving multiple values in that function call.

Comment: Why is 3 being passed in as the second positional argument? I thought it would be passed in as the third.

Comment: @asad: positional arguments are passed first, then keyword arguments. Hence it's the second positional argument.

Answer (score 1):

This would work - note the order in which things are presented

```
 f(1, *(2,), c=3, **{'d': 4})
```

Comment: Why was this down voted it is 100% correct and illustrates the issue

Comment: You might point out that `f(1, c=3, *(2,), **{'d': 4})` also works, where his attempt fails, to emphasize that a keyword argument is different from a positional argument.

Answer (score 1):

You assign `b` both as a positional and keyword argument.

As defined in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-argument):

> *positional argument*: an argument that is not a keyword argument. Positional arguments can appear at the beginning of an argument list and/or be passed as elements of an iterable preceded by *.
>
> *keyword argument:* an argument preceded by an identifier (e.g. name=) in a function call or passed as a value in a dictionary preceded by **.

Positional arguments are always assigned in order. So when you do this:

```
>>> f(1, b=2, *(3,), **{'d': 4})   # Same as f(1, b=2, 3, d=4)
```

The two positional arguments, `1` and `3` are assigned to `a` and `b`, respectively. As you also assign it as a keyword argument (`b=2`), `b` therefore get multiple values assigned.

**Some restrictions**

If you need more information on how calls are defined, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls). Notably, *only keyword arguments may follow `*expression`*, and *`**expression` has to be the last argument in the call*.

**Solution**

Reorder the arguments so that the positional arguments always are listed first:

```
>>> f(1, *(2,), c=3, **{'d': 4})   # Same as f(1, 2, c=3, d=4)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this doesn't work: f(1, *(2,), **{'c': 3}, d=4)